# looping through Page Controls - using same logic for multiple control types

Tags: c#, asp.net, reflection, web-controls

I'm looping through the page controls like so

```
      foreach (Control ctrl in control.Controls)
      {
          if (ctrl is System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox || ctrl is System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label)
          {
          }
      }
```

I want to be able to declare a variable inside this if statements that is the same type as 'ctrl' in the foreach so that I can inspect the properties of the control and perform some manipulations that way.  I don't want to duplicate code, for example, if 'ctrl' is a textbox, or label, because I would be executing the same code for those 2 web control types.

Any help leading me in the right direction is greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: How can it be? TextBox and Label are two different types of classes? They have different properties (except for the ones derived from common base classes)! Without individually type-casting to each one of them (which you are saying a duplicating the code), how can you write an understandable and portable code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the `ITextControl` interface:

```
foreach (Control ctrl in control.Controls)
{
    ITextControl text = ctrl as ITextControl;
    if (text != null)
    {
        // now you can use the "Text" property in here,
        // regardless of the type of the control.
    }
}
```

You can also use the `OfType` extension method here to clean this up a bit:

```
foreach (ITextControl text in control.Controls.OfType<ITextControl>())
{
    // now you can use the "Text" property in here,
    // regardless of the type of the control.
}
```

Comment: I want to access properties of 'ctrl' such as CssClass, and casting to ITextControl does not give the accomodations (that I saw) for me to do that.  Thanks for the quick response Andrew!

Comment: Try using `WebControl` then instead of `ITextControl` that will give you access to `CssClass` at least.  The trick is to find the lowest common denominator between your types.

Comment: ok - that is the direction I was headed myself, too - thanks for confirming my thought :)